# Distribution of the summation of K-smallest random variables choosen from N random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider $N$ i.i.d. random variables $x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_N$, where $x_n\in\mathcal{X}_n=\{X_n^1,X_n^2,\cdots, X_n^M\}$ and $p_n(X_n)=\Pr[x_n = X_n]$. For a given realization $(X_n)_{n=1,2,\cdots,N}$ of $(x_n)_{n=1,2,\cdots,N}$, let $Y_K$ be the summation of the K-smallest elements of $(X_n)_{n=1,2,\cdots,N}$.

Is it possible to calculate the probability mass function of $Y_k$ and the size of the set of all possible $Y_K$?

Thanks!